# Memory Usage Concern with Controlled Components

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm using controlled components in my React forms. My concern is those input fields where the user can type in text that can be long.

Because I'm using Redux for state management, state is immutable. So, in a description field, if I were to type, "Some description!", the state values that are kept in my redux store are:

```
S
So
Som
Some
Some 
Some d
Some de
[and so on]
```

In the life time of a user's session, memory usage can get a bit heavy just storing all the previous states of these form fields. This is especially concerning on mobile devices with limited system resources.

What's a good strategy to manage memory consumption of my redux store? Is there a way to flush out some parts of the store? I wouldn't want to wipe out everything but it would be beneficial if some parts could be flushed out in a controlled way.

Comment: Are you saying that Redux keeps all previous values in addition to the current value, or do you have code that does that?

Comment: Low hanging fruit would be adding a debounce to the `onChange` event. Not ideal, but could help if there isn't some kind of garbage collector like you are looking for.

Comment: You may use a `setTimeout` before calling an action in those cases, so that you don't have to call the action each time the user press a character. I give an example in an answer.

Comment: @Manolo, that wouldn't really work because it's a controlled component -- meaning I rely on the redux store for the value. Unless, I update the value in the store, the component won't display it correctly. One can come up with another hack but that's a slippery slope. Before long, things can get out of hand.

Comment: @JordanRunning That's the nature of Redux. That's what immutable means.

Comment: @Sam That's not at all what ["immutable"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) means. Where are you getting this? If you design your state and reducers such that every single previous state is kept, then that's what will happen. But you would have to do that deliberately; it's not something that Redux does automatically, nor is it a natural consequence of immutability.

Comment: @JordanRunning Redux pattern is to be immutable. This is why in the reducer, we use `Object.assign({}, state, newValue)` pattern. I guess you can mutate values but where do you see Redux usage with mutating state?

Comment: You don't mutate state in Redux and I never suggested that you should. What I said is that neither Redux nor immutable data structures/techniques keep previous states around by default. I don't know where you picked up that idea, but it's false.

Comment: @JordanRunning I guess I'm mixing two things here. The behavior of DevTools and Redux. To reiterate a question I just asked another poster. when I use `Object.assign`, is the previous state removed?

Comment: Object.assign merges two arrays into a target array. So `Object.assign({}, state, newValue)` would return a new merged object and `state` & `newVal` will be "destroyed" once the function completes.

Comment: [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) copies the properties of the second, third, etc. arguments onto the first argument, then returns the first argument. When you do `Object.assign(a, b, c)`, first the properties of `b` are copied onto `a`, then the properties of `c` are copied onto `a`, and then `a` is returned. If `b` and `c` have a property with the same name, `a` will get the value from `c` because it's copied second. When the first argument is an empty object (`{}`), you're creating a new object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're misunderstanding how Redux works, and how immutable data updates work.  Redux does not keep around previous versions of the state tree or actions by default.  The Redux DevTools do track a specific number of previous actions and resulting state trees, but only in development.  Any objects that are no longer referenced will be cleaned up by the JS garbage collector.

See http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/Performance.html#performance-state-memory, [Is there any way to "commit" the state in Redux to free memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35627553/is-there-any-way-to-commit-the-state-in-redux-to-free-memory/35634004) , and [ngredux state with big data collection, memory concerns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42686735/ngredux-state-with-big-data-collection-memory-concerns) for more information.

Comment: This is enlightening, though a bit confused. If I use `Object.assign` so that I do not mutate the state, is the previous state removed and only the current one kept?

Comment: Redux will no longer have its `currentState` variable point to the root state tree object, so that will get GC'd (assuming no other parts of the app reference it). Any parts of the old state tree that the new state tree does not re-use will also get GC'd.